# Mongodb authentication using elixir-mongo

Tags: mongodb, elixir

I have just started using Elixir, so I figure I have some basic misunderstanding going on here. Here is the code...

```
defmodule Mdb do
  def connect(collection, this_db \\ "db-test") do
    {:ok, mongo} = Mongo.connect("db-test.some-mongo-server.com", 12345)
    db = mongo |> Mongo.db(this_db)
    db |> Mongo.auth("user", "secretpassword")
    db
 end
```

`end`

I start with `iex -S mix`
and when I try `db = Mdb.connect("users")` I get

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Mongo.auth/3
               Mongo.auth(%Mongo.Db{auth: nil, mongo: %Mongo.Server{host: 'db-test.some-mongo-server.com', id_prefix: 12641, mode: :passive, opts: %{}, port: 12345, socket: #Port<0.5732>, timeout: 6000}, name: "db-stage", opts: %{mode: :passive, timeout: 6000}}, "user", "secretpassword")
    (mdb_play) lib/mdb.ex:7: Mdb.connect/2`

I looks like Mongo.auth/3 is undefined, but that makes no sense to me. Can any one point me towards my error?
thanks for the help

Comment: Not sure about the problem, but pay attention to the last two lines of the function: I never used the `Mongo` library, but I'm pretty sure that doing `db |> Mongo.auth(...)` without assigning the result to anything is pointless. Usually in Elixir that `Mongo.auth(db, ...)` will return a new *authenticated* instance of a DB. Don't confuse `db |> Mongo.auth(...)` with an "imperative" `db.auth()` :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just played around it, and faced the same error. As in the error message, `Mongo.auth` seems not defined, and it might be `Mongo.Db.auth` instead. However, I faced another error (ArgumentError) on `Mongo.Db.auth` too. It may be certain issue in the library.

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
            :erlang.byte_size
...
    (mongo) lib/mongo_request.ex:43: Mongo.Request.cmd/3
    (mongo) lib/mongo_db.ex:44: Mongo.Db.auth/1
```

I'm not familiar with the library, but after small change in `Mongo.Db.auth`, normal call seems started working.

I tried with the following sequence.

```
mongo = Mongo.connect!(server, port)
db = mongo |> Mongo.db(db_name)
db |> Mongo.Db.auth(user_name, password)
collection = db |> Mongo.Db.collection(collection_name)
collection |> Mongo.Collection.count()
```

The change I tried is in the following fork-repo.

https://github.com/parroty/elixir-mongo

Comment: Ah, I get my initial mistake. Thank you. Now studying your change.

Comment: I made a couple of more changes on my fork (frpaulas/elixir-mongo) to make Mongo.Db.auth a little more consistent w/ checkiz/elixir-mongo - I think